# I can't retrieve data from Firebase database by user input to TextView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Anyone help me please. I don't understand what I should to do to solve my problem.

I am not able to retrieve data from Firebase database. I am using Java language in android studio. I want to showing "Kode barang" which in database is "kode" and "Harga Barang" which in database is "harga". All of them will show by user input "Nama barang" which in database is "nama".

[Screenshot form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGUFe.png)

If I'm trying to input data in "Nama barang" which is the same as data value in "nama" in database and after that I'm input "jumlah beli" (in english: quantity) and then click "Cek" (english: check"), my app get forced close.

[My database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlO07.png)

**This is fragment class**

```
    public class TransPenjFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView autotgl;
    TextView tvkdbrg;
    TextView tvhrgbrg;
    TextView totalpj;
    EditText edtTextnamabrg;
    EditText edtTextjmlbeli;
    Button btnCek, btnProses, btnHapus;
    private FirebaseDatabase firedb;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private ArrayList<BarangDB> daftarbarang;
    private PenjualanAdapter adapter;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trans_penj, container, false);
        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        autotgl = view.findViewById(R.id.autotgl);
        tvkdbrg = view.findViewById(R.id.tvkdbrg);
        tvhrgbrg = view.findViewById(R.id.tvhrgbrg);
        totalpj = view.findViewById(R.id.total);
        edtTextnamabrg = view.findViewById(R.id.edtTextnamabrg);
        edtTextjmlbeli = view.findViewById(R.id.edtTextjmlbeli);
        btnCek = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCek);
        btnProses = view.findViewById(R.id.btnProses);
        btnHapus = view.findViewById(R.id.btnHapus);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getActivity());
        firedb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = firedb.getReference();

        btnCek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String namabrg = edtTextnamabrg.getText().toString().trim();
                myRef = firedb.getInstance().getReference().child("Barang");
                Query check = myRef.orderByChild("nama").equalTo(namabrg);
                check.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if(snapshot.exists()){
                            BarangDB barang = snapshot.getValue(BarangDB.class);
                            String namabrgfromDB = snapshot.child(namabrg).child("nama").getValue(String.class);
                            if(namabrgfromDB.equals(namabrg)){
                                tvkdbrg.setText(barang.getKode());
                                tvhrgbrg.setText(barang.getHarga());
                            }else{
                                Snackbar.make(btnCek, "Barang yang dimasukkan tidak ada di daftar barang",
                                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }else{
                            Snackbar.make(btnCek, "Tidak tersedia",
                                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getDetails() + " "
                                + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                String jmlbeli = edtTextjmlbeli.getText().toString().trim();

                double jb =Double.parseDouble(jmlbeli);
                double hb = Double.parseDouble(tvhrgbrg.getText().toString());
                double total = (jb*hb);

                totalpj.setText(" "+total);

            }
        });
```

`edtTextnamabrg` is `editText` to input "Nama barang" from user to be the same as "nama" in database.

`tvkdbrg` is `textView` to retrieve data "Kode Barang" or "kode" from database.

`tvhrgbrg` is `textView` to retrieve data "Harga barang" or "harga" from database.

**This is my database model**

```
    public class BarangDB implements Serializable {
    private String kode;
    private String nama;
    private String harga;
    private String stok;
    private String key;

    public BarangDB(){ }

    public BarangDB (String kode, String nama, String harga, String stok){
        this.kode = kode;
        this.nama = nama;
        this.harga = harga;
        this.stok = stok;
    }

    public String getKey() { return key;}

    public void setKey(String key) { this.key = key; }

    public String getKode() { return kode;}

    public void setKode(String kode) { this.kode = kode; }

    public String getNama() { return nama; }

    public void setNama(String nama) { this.nama = nama; }

    public String getHarga() { return harga; }

    public void setHarga(String harga) { this.harga = harga; }

    public String getStok() { return stok; }

    public void setStok(String stok) { this.stok = stok; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " "+kode+"\n" + " "+nama+"\n" + " "+harga+ "\n" + " "+stok;
    }
    }
```

Logcat

```
    2020-07-25 23:07:30.250 20490-20490/com.example.aplikasiskripsi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aplikasiskripsi, PID: 20490
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at com.example.aplikasiskripsi.TransPenjFragment$1.onClick(TransPenjFragment.java:120)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6605)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6582)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Sharing logs/stack traces can help others understand your problem better.

Comment: yeah, already edited, thank you for reminding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to extract a child under `Barang` key which has key-value pair `nama: {value of namabrg}`. Note that the result in `snapshot` does not match your `BarangDB` class structure. `snapshot` will return you the next structure:

[image: Actual returned value]

It means that your `BarangDB` class must hold another variable of type `Energen`, which will hold other variables (mode, harga, nama, stok).

And I see you partially understand that and almost got it right.

You need to change two lines. From this:

```
BarangDB barang = snapshot.getValue(BarangDB.class);
String namabrgfromDB = snapshot.child(namabrg).child("nama").getValue(String.class);
```

To this:

```
BarangDB barang = snapshot.child(namabrg).getValue(BarangDB.class);
String namabrgfromDB = barang.getNama();
```

And it should be enough.

Comment: Yes I have changed it and the problem has been resolved. But let me ask another question because I don't really understand, how to retrieve data from 2 databases into a fragment? Once again, thank you so so so much Sir:) your help means a lot to me

Comment: You can have multiple databases per project only if you subscribed to a paid plan. [Here you can see the difference](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) between two subscription plans: free and paid. Search for "Database" word on the page.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. I mean can we get data from 2 childs from firebase? For example, I have 3 childs in OnlineShopApp, that is Item (item_name, item_types, etc), Supplier(Supp_name, Supp_phone, etc), and Sale. In the Sale's fragment,  i want to retrieve data from Item(that is item_name) and Supplier (that is Supp_name). Can i get data from both in Sale's fragment?

Comment: You can do it the same way as `firedb.getInstance().getReference().child("Barang");`. Just instead of `"Barang"` put something else that you need. You can basically have two or more references: `DatabaseReference myRef_barang = firedb.getInstance().getReference().child("Barang");` and `DatabaseReference myRef_supplier = firedb.getInstance().getReference().child("Supplier");`

Comment: yeah i got that point. you are very kind, thank you so much and god bless you! :)

Comment: Sir I'm sorry if I disturb your time again and again, but I need your help again. if you want to help me, please look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/63206431/13962853. Thank you very much, sir. Your help means a lot to me. @JeneaVranceanu